# How do I presentModalViewController at startup?

Tags: ios

I would like to present a modal view controller *first* at start up if certain conditions are present. I am using the following code:

```
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

This code displays the modal view controller from **viewDidAppear**, however, it does not work from **viewWillAppear** or **viewDidLoad**. The problem with putting the code in **viewDidAppear** is that it flashes the parent view before loading the modal view.

Comment: Why don't you make the initial parent view invisible/transparent on initial startup so that it doesn't flash? When the model view is dismissed make it visible.

Comment: I was planning to use the default image to cover the parent view on initial start up. However, that seems so hokey. I was hoping for an explanation of how views were handled and a pointer to the sequence of methods that are called during start-up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to do this, as soon as the app starts, but only if you need to do it just *one time*.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"firstLaunch"]){
        [self performSelector:@selector(yourModalView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
        [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstLaunch"];

    }          

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

If you need to present that viewController at every start with some conditions, then use the bdev code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just create a slight delay in your viewDidLoad:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(presentVC) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

And in that method

```
-(void) presentVC{
     [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Adding a delay does not help (I used a delay of 0). The parent view is still displayed first before the desired view is shown.